# Buscar e pessoas que possuem o mesmo nome, sobrenome e data de nascimento

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, oracle, oracle11g

Como posso fazer para realizar um select no Oracle que traga todas as pessoas que possuem o mesmo nome, sobrenome e data de nascimento porem, possuem ID's diferentes.

Comment: Para mais ajuda, mostre-nos o seu modelo (tabela e nomes dos campos) e o que você já tentou fazer (seu `select` por exemplo) para que possamos te ajudar.

Comment: A Tabela em si é muito grande, poderia ser só um select de uma tabela ficticia para eu entender a ideia. Ex:  Tabela = Pessoa Física, Campos: ID, Nome, Sobrenome, Data_Nasc

Answer (score 1):

Considerando que o ID é único para cada registro, agrupe por esses campos usando o GROUP BY e filtre os registros com mais de uma ocorrência usando o HAVING.

```
SELECT NOME, SOBRENOME, DATA_NASCIMENTO FROM PESSOAS 
GROUP BY NOME, SOBRENOME, DATA_NASCIMENTO HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Caso você queira visualizar os registros como um todo, uma opção é:

```
SELECT 
  A.* 
FROM 
  PESSOAS A JOIN PESSOAS B ON A.NOME = B.NOME AND A.SOBRENOME = B.SOBRENOME 
    AND A.DATA_NASCIMENTO = B.DATA_NASCIMENTO AND A.ID <> B.ID;
```

Comment: Obrigado Davy Machado!! Ajudou muito.

Answer (score 0):

Ampliando um pouco a solução do @Davy Machado

```
SELECT *
FROM PESSOAS 
WHERE (NOME, SOBRENOME, DATA_NASCIMENTO) IN (SELECT NOME, SOBRENOME, DATA_NASCIMENTO 
                                             FROM PESSOAS 
                                             GROUP BY NOME, SOBRENOME, DATA_NASCIMENTO 
                                             HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ID) > 1)
ORDER BY NOME, SOBRENOME, DATA_NASCIMENTO , ID;
```